# Added multiple records to DataSet but only one record is stored in database (C#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataset, insert-update, updatecommand

OK this may be a bit of a long one but please bear with me. I searched high and low and I can't seem to find a clear answer about my particular issue.

As the subject above states, I am using `DataSet`s to retrieve, edit, insert and update records in a database. However all the other functions work as expected except the insert. What happens is that when I insert new records into the data set all looks fine as using the watch feature I can see the new records in the dataset. But after I end the edit, accept the changes and do the update, only one record is sent to the database. See some code below. I have used some bindings as well.

There code is split into different functions as follows: `SetAdapaterCommands`, `FillDataSets`, `SendToDatabase` and `BindToUI`. Can anyone see anything wrong?

Or is there something about how the dataset insert and update commands work that I'm missing?

I should maybe also say that I am updating another parent table before this one. Not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Start set adapter commands

Select command

```
#region Select Task Command
queryString = "SELECT value1, value2, value3 FROM Table1;";

taskCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
#endregion Select Task Command
```

Update command

```
#region Update Task Command
queryString = "UPDATE Table1 SET value1 = @value1, value2 = @value2, value3 = @value3" +
              "WHERE value1 = @value1;";

taskUpdateCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);

taskUpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@value1", SqlDbType.Char, 10, "value1");
taskUpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@value2", SqlDbType.Char, 10, "value2");
taskUpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@value3", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "value3");

taskAdapter.UpdateCommand = taskUpdateCommand;

SqlParameter taskParameter = taskUpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@oldValue1", SqlDbType.Char, 10, "value1");
taskParameter.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;
#endregion Update Task Command
```

Insert command

```
#region Insert Task Command
queryString = "INSERT INTO Table1 (value1, value2, value3) " +
              "VALUES (@value1, @value2, @value3);";

taskInsertCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);

taskInsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@value1", SqlDbType.Char, 10, "value1");
taskInsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@value2", SqlDbType.Char, 10, "value2");
taskInsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@value3", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "value3");            

taskAdapter.InsertCommand = taskInsertCommand;
#endregion Insert Task Command
```

End set adapter commands

Fill data set

```
private void loadFromDatabase()
{
    #region Load Data and From Database 
    SetAdapterCommands();

    #region Load Tasks
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        taskAdapter.SelectCommand = taskCommand;
        taskAdapter.Fill(Table1DataSet);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    #endregion Load Tasks
}
```

Send changes to database

```
private void updateDatabase()
{
    try
    {
        Table1BindingSource.EndEdit();
        Table1DataSet.AcceptChanges();
        taskAdapter.Update(Table1DataSet);
    }
    catch(System.Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Update Failed");
    }
}
```

Bind to UI

```
textBoxValue1.DataBindings.Add("Text", Table1BindingSource, "value1");
textBoxValue2.DataBindings.Add("Text", Table1BindingSource, "value2");
textBoxValue3.DataBindings.Add("Text", Table1BindingSource, "value3");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common mistake. DataSet.[AcceptChanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.acceptchanges(v=vs.110).aspx) changes the [RowState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate(v=vs.110).aspx) of every DataRow in every DataTable of your DataSet to the value [DataRowState.Unchanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowstate(v=vs.110).aspx).

So if you call `AcceptChanges` the following call to `Update` doesn't find any row to update, delete or insert.

You should simply remove the call to `AcceptChanges`.

A bit of background. When you edit a row its `RowState` is changed to `DataRowState.Modified` (for inserts we have `DataRowState.Added` and for deleted rows we have `DataRowState.Deleted`)

The Update call of the DataAdapter searches the rows in these states to prepare and send the relative UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE to the datastore.

I think that AcceptChanges has a confusing name and many people thinks that this call is required before sending the Update but it is quite the contrary.

Comment: Thanks Steve! This solved my problem. I was using the AcceptChanges as I was using code example from two different sources to solve different problems as I developed the code.